# How to implement a multidimensional array shuffling in CSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, multidimensional-array

I wonder if it is possible to implement a general Julia\Matlab alike `View` function in C# that would work for arrays of any dimensions (eg `[,,]` and `[,,,]`) as they do it in [array slicer\mover `view`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6.2/stdlib/arrays/#Views-(SubArrays-and-other-view-types)-1). So I wonder if there is a library that provides similar functionality for CSharp multidimentional arrays or how to implement it in C#?

Comment: So, particularly what function do you want to be implemented? Just like `view(A, :, 1)` which should return the first whole column?

Comment: Sure, you'd just use `Array.Rank` to get the number of dimensions and `Array.GetLength` to get the size of each dimension.  There's nothing built in for that and this is the wrong place to ask about libraries.  If you give the code a try and run into problems then that would make a good question.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Note that if you attempt this then your method should return a class that contains a reference to the original array so that changes to it will be reflected there.

Comment: To expand on @Enigmativity's comment. SO has other communities for other types of activities, such as code reviews, user experience, etc., etc. For software recommendations you can join SO's Software Recommendations forum at: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is twofold:

1. Use a wrapper class that holds a reference to the master array
2. Use the `Array` base class to make it polymorphic

**Wrapper**

```
class View<T>
{
    private readonly Array array;
    private readonly int dim;
    private readonly int slice;

    public View(Array array, int dim, int slice)
    {
        this.array = array;
        this.dim = dim;
        this.slice = slice;
    }

    public T this[params int[] indexes]
    {
        get { return (T)array.GetValue(BaseIndexesFor(indexes)); }
        set { array.SetValue(value, BaseIndexesFor(indexes)); }
    }

    private int[] BaseIndexesFor(int[] indexes)
    {
        if (indexes.Length != array.Rank - 1) throw new ArgumentException("indexes");

        int i_index = 0;
        int[] baseIndexes = new int[array.Rank];

        for (int i = 0; i < baseIndexes.Length; i++)
        {
            baseIndexes[i] = (i == dim) ? slice : indexes[i_index++];
        }

        return baseIndexes;
    }
}
```

**2D example**

```
var A = new int[,]
{
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 4, 5, 6 },
    { 7, 8, 9 }
};

/* View(Array array, int dim, int slice)
 * 
 * For 2 dimensional array:
 * dim=0 -> rows
 * dim=1 -> columns
*/
// From second dimension slice index 1
// Or simply, take column with index 1
var B = new View<int>(A, 1, 1); 

B[2] = 0;
Console.WriteLine(A[2, 1]); // 0
```

**3D examples**

```
var C = new int[,,]
{
    { 
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8, 9 }
    },
    {
        { 11, 12, 13 },
        { 14, 15, 16 },
        { 17, 18, 19 }
    },
    {
        { 21, 22, 23 },
        { 24, 25, 26 },
        { 27, 28, 29 }
    }
};

/* From first dimension slice index 2
 * { 21, 22, 23 },
 * { 24, 25, 26 },
 * { 27, 28, 29 }
 */
var D = new View<int>(C, 0, 2);

D[1, 1] = 0;
Console.WriteLine(C[2, 1, 1]); // 0

/* From third dimension slice index 0
 * { 1, 4, 7 },
 * { 11, 14, 17 },
 * { 21, 24, 27 }
 */
var E = new View<int>(C, 2, 0);

E[2, 0] = 0;
Console.WriteLine(C[2, 0, 0]); // 0
```